# How can I fix a loud fan on Linux?

Tags: hardware, temperature

When I turn on my Dell desktop, it starts up just fine (quiet), then the fan kicks in super loud and is consistent even when the operating systems goes into standby mode. How can I diagnose a fan's operating tempatures and then set them on start up?

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard already has (it should) sensors to detect temperatures and then and only then, tell the fan to operate at specific speed (you can set it by motherboard settings).

That is said and true, if the fan already has a controlling pin installed at the motherboard, otherwise the fan would just run at 100%.

To read motherboard sensors, use the command `sensors` from the package `lm_sensors`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an old fan, and louder than it should be in normal operation, consider using a drop of oil on the lubrication point as described e.g. [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/quiet-noisy-computer-fans-with-a-drop-of-oil/). The noise such a fan makes is very typical and easy to recognize, but I can't describe it properly. I fixed a very load power supply fan successfully this way.

To find out how to control fan speed under Linux, please describe which fan it is (Power supply? CPU? something else?). Run `sensors-detect` from the `lm_sensors` package, and you may need to load additional kernel modules to control the fan.

Comment: I used that same article to quiet my fan.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, fans cause the frame to resonate. If the fan itself is not defective, in need of a drop of oil, or its blades misaligned, use rubber-foam between it and the case. The decibel value will drop noticeably.